# Using Qt3D with Qt5

Tags: qt, qt5, qt3d

I'm trying to use the Qt3D library with Qt5.

I followed these steps:

- I've installed Qt5 (on Arch Linux 64bit) at this path: `/Qt5.0.0`
- I've cloned `git://gitorious.org/qt/qt3d.git`
- I've built qt3d (`/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/gcc_64/lib/qmake`, `make`, `make install`)

Now I have the right files in the right places, and if I manually add

```
   LIBS += -L/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/gcc_64/lib/ -lQt53D
   INCLUDEPATH += /Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/gcc_64/include/Qt3D/
   DEPENDPATH += /Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/gcc_64/include/Qt3D/
```

to my .pro file I'm able to include Qt3D headers (like `qglabstractscene.h`).

Unfortunately I'm still unable to compile the project because the library code refers to itself as being part of Qt3D:

```
#include <Qt3D/qt3dglobal.h>
```

Is there a way to make Qt understand an `INCLUDEPATH` is a Qt module?
Any suggestion is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem must be related to QtCreator.

Using qmake directly builds the library succesfully, while using QtCreator fail.

Adding

```
QT += 3d
```

works too